# How to specify app_secret for a Koala object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, koala

In devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, app_id, 'app_secret', :scope => 'email', info_fields: 'email, name, address, birthday, age_range, first_name, gender, hometown, location '
```

In user.rb (model)

```
def facebook
    @facebook ||=  Koala::Facebook::API.new(self.oauth_token)
  end
```

The oauth token for the user object is set and then the following is called.

```
user.facebook.get_object("me")
```

This is the response

```
{"name"=>"name", "id"=>"uid"}
```

I do not get any additional information like address, email, image link etc, although, if the user is made to sign in via omniauth-facebook, I get all the params. What should I do?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”. You need explicitly to ask for the fields you want returned now.

Answer (score 0):

It's because each user has certain things restricted or granted by default, their security settings. Oauth, bumps the user and says "if you want access to this app, you'll need to agree to let us have these permissions on your account" -- the user says ok and you get the info you need.  Users with certain security settings will also let you see other about-me info.

So... the simple answer is to use an oauth login.  that will ensure the token you get back gives you access to the things you list in the scope.

Out of curiosity, is there a reason you aren't asking for oauth login already?